# Fastest way to swap alternate bytes on ARM Cortex M4 using gcc

Tags: gcc, arm, endianness

I need to swap alternate bytes in a buffer as quickly as possible in an embedded system using ARM Cortex M4 processor. I use gcc. The amount of data is variable but the max is a little over 2K. it doesn't matter if a few extra bytes are converted because I can use an over-sized buffer.

I know that the ARM has the `REV16` instruction, which I can use to swap alternate bytes in a 32-bit word. What I don't know is:

1. Is there a way of getting at this instruction in gcc without resorting to assembler? The `__builtin_bswap16` intrinsic appears to operate on 16-bit words only. Converting 4 bytes at a time will surely be faster than converting 2 bytes.
2. Does the Cortex M4 have a reorder buffer and/or do register renaming? If not, what do I need to do to minimise pipeline stalls when I convert the dwords of the buffer in a partially-unrolled loop?

For example, is this code efficient, where `REV16` is appropriately defined to resolve (1):

```
uint32_t *buf = ... ;
size_t n = ... ;  // (number of bytes to convert + 15)/16
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    uint32_t a = buf[0];
    uint32_t b = buf[1];
    uint32_t c = buf[2];
    uint32_t d = buf[3];
    REV16(a, a);
    REV16(b, b);
    REV16(c, c);
    REV16(d, d);
    buf[0] = a;
    buf[1] = b;
    buf[2] = c;
    buf[3] = d;
    buf += 4;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with [inline assembler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).  It is not portable, but neither is `__builtin_bswap16`.  `__builtin_bswap16` is only good for GCC with multiple CPU types.  Mostly for libc writers targeting GCC.  Highly targeted conditional code that throws an error when porting would probably be acceptable to most people.  Just put some good comments.  See: [bswapdi2.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/lib/bswapsdi2.S) in the Linux kernel.  Your system maybe memory bound and not CPU bound.

Comment: See: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/nEydDt) for some straight 'C' using the mask method of 'bswapdi2.s' for arch<ARMv6 (from David Seal).

Comment: Thanks, I can use inline assembler if no other way is equally fast. Can I just use: `asm("rev16 a,a");`  to apply the rev16 operation to my variable `a` in the above example?

Comment: @dc42 See https://godbolt.org/g/JyZBZp for an example, you can see the compiler inlines the function call to `Rev16` is inlined so you end up with a single instruction.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the `__builtin_bswap16` function for the reason you stated, it works on 16 bit words so will 0 the other halfword. I guess the reason for this is to keep the intrinsic working the same on processors which don't have an instruction behaving similarly to `REV16` on ARM.

The function

```
uint32_t swap(uint32_t in)
{
  in = __builtin_bswap32(in);
  in = (in >> 16) | (in << 16);
  return in;
}
```

compiles to (ARM GCC 5.4.1 -O3 -std=c++11 -march=armv7-m -mtune=cortex-m4 -mthumb)

```
    rev     r0, r0
    ror     r0, r0, #16
    bx      lr
```

And you could probably ask the compiler to inline it, which would give you 2 instructions per 32bit word. I can't think of a way to get GCC to generate `REV16` with a 32bit operand, without declaring your own function with inline assembly.

**EDIT**

As a follow up, and based on artless noise's comment about the non portability of the `__builtin_bswap` functions, [the compiler recognizes](https://godbolt.org/g/jsKvHb)

```
uint32_t swap(uint32_t in)
{
  in = ((in & 0xff000000) >> 24) | ((in & 0x00FF0000) >> 8) | ((in & 0x0000FF00) << 8) | ((in & 0xFF) << 24);
  in = (in >> 16) | (in << 16);
  return in;
}
```

and creates the same 3 instruction function as above, so that is a more portable way to achieve it. Whether different compilers would produce the same output though...

**EDIT EDIT**

If inline assembler is allowed, the following function

```
inline uint32_t Rev16(uint32_t a)
{
  asm ("rev16 %1,%0"
          : "=r" (a)
          : "r" (a));
  return a;
}
```

gets inlined, and acts as a single instruction as can be seen [here.](https://godbolt.org/g/JyZBZp)